# Generate calculated column with row_number() over partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-structures, database-design

I want to generate a column containing a unique number based on state and number of times that has come up in database

It's like

```
Ny_1
Ny_2
St_1
Ny_3
St_2
Up_1
Ny_4
```

And so on...

I want a persisted calculated column

Other column must be like

```
Name   |  state   |  total    |  ticket no
Abc    |  Ny      |  1        |  Ny_1
Cda.   |  Ny      |  2        |  NY_2
Xyz.   |  St      |  1        |  ST_1
```

I can generate this in a view by using partition by
and concatenate the result

But I am not sure if I can create a calculated column based on row_number() over (partition by something order by something)

Just 2-question

1) can I use partition in a calculated column

2) is there a better approach

(update from comments:)

Look the column that I am trying to generate will turn out to be the primary key...all the other column with be attached to it... It's business requirement... It has to be done this way only...

I have to generate a ticket number in database which should be like... State_number of tickets in the state_ this is the number all the database will be attached to.

It's an excel sheet I to convert to sql table... And it's the ticket number I am talking about...it has to be generated this way.

Comment: Can you show the table schema and exactly what you want to partition by and order by?

Comment: It's an excel sheet I to convert to sql table... And it's the ticket number I am talking about...it has to be generated this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question 1**) Can I use [window function with] partition [by] in a calculated column?

**Answer**: Yes, by using a function to return the value, but **not** `persisted` because it would be non-deterministic.

> **Question 2**) Is there a better approach?

**Answer**: Yes, this should **not** be the primary key.

Why would you want this to be your primary key?

Saying that this is a business requirement doesn't make it a good idea. Find another way to accommodate your business requirements without them forcing you into horrible design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

In `Computed column` we cannot use `window` functions, instead you can go for `View`

```
CREATE VIEW state_num
AS
  SELECT state,
         seq_state = state
                     + Cast(Row_number()OVER(partition BY state ORDER BY state) AS VARCHAR(50))
  FROM   yourtable
```

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2012` and above then use `CONCAT` function which does not require *explicit* conversion.

```
CREATE VIEW state_num
AS
  SELECT state,
         seq_state = Concat(state, Row_number()OVER(partition BY state ORDER BY state))
  FROM   yourtable
```

Comment: Look the column that I am trying to generate will turn out to be the primary key...all the other column with be attached to it... It's business requirement... It has to be done this way only... Please help me

Comment: @Vikram - As i already mentioned you cannot use `row_number` window function in `Computed column`

Comment: I have updated the question.... Please help me out how should I do it... In database only not in view

Comment: @Vikram - Can you clearly say whats your requirement. Your update is kind of confusing

Comment: I have to generate a ticket number in database which should be like... State_number of tickets in the state_ this is the number all the database will be attached to...

Comment: Somehow I can't pull it off

Comment: @Vikram - what is `total` column ? how is it populated.

Comment: That's is what I am trying to figure out.... It should be like number of total rows of a state

Comment: say I have five tickets from Up and 3 from HR ... Then the ticket should be like up_1 and up_2 so on... I thought I should add a running total with partition by to solve it.. But add you said it can't be done...what should I do